# PyQt 5.6.2 / 5.9.1 on Windows 10 - WindowStaysOnTopHint doesn't work

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qwidget

*PyQt 5.6.2, 5.9.1, Anaconda, vscode, Windows 10 x64.*

Setting `QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint` in `super().__init__()` or via `self.setWindowFlags()` does nothing. **With Qt 4.8.7 (PyQt 4.11.4) the flag works as expected.**

I can fix this using Windows API (`HWND_TOPMOST` flag):

```
import sys
try:
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
except ImportError:
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui as QtWidgets

class Form1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Push", self)
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.ontop = False

    def clicked(self):
        self.ontop = not self.ontop
        self.windowStaysOnTopHint(self.ontop)

    def windowStaysOnTopHint(self, b=True):
        try:
            import win32gui, win32con
            flag = win32con.HWND_TOPMOST if b else win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST
            win32gui.SetWindowPos(self.winId(), flag, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOSIZE | win32con.SWP_NOMOVE)
        except ModuleNotFoundError:
            pass
        if b:
            flag = self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        else:
            flag = self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        self.setGeometry(self.geometry())  # `setWindowFlags` resets size if setGeometry is never called
        self.setWindowFlags(flag)
        self.show()

print(QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR)
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
form1 = Form1()
form1.show()
app.exec_()
```

I can use `win32gui.SetWindowPos` and remove `setWindowFlags` block at all. But I really want to know what's the reason of this behaviour.

Comment: ...and now `WindowStaysOnTopHint` works as expected in both Qt5 versions in different Anaconda environments:/

Comment: I think here's the bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50271